# Counting number of lines in input string in C

Tags: c, eof, getchar

Here's my problem-

```
char c,int nl=1;
printf("Enter string");
while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
{
   if(c=='\n')
      ++nl;
}
printf("Number of lines=%d",nl);
```

No error. But when I give input it continues to take input (do not comes out of console screen). Why compiler is unable to read EOF value ?
I also tried `while((c=getchar())!='\0')` but doesn't work !

Comment: Change type of `c` from `char` to `int`

Comment: If the input doesn't come from a file, you can terminate it with one of Crl-D (Unix) or Ctrl-Z (Windows). If you don't do that, the interactive shell will just wait for more input.

Comment: Read e.g. [this `getchar` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar). Pay close attention to the return type of the function.

Comment: Generic advice: If something doesn't work as expected, (re-) read the docs on the functions used, *carefully*.

Comment: Apart from the RTFM part, it is quite reasonable to ask why `getchar` doesn't return a char. Welcome to C.

Answer (score 1):

`char` is not capable to store `EOF`. Use `int` to store the return value of `getchar()`.

Try changing

```
char c,int nl=1;
```

to

```
int c,nl=1;
```

Comment: Same thing still happening. It doesn't break.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `c` as `int` instead of `char`.